Error in server error 503 service unavailable the site cannot be reached in ASP.NET Core 8
I have a hosted web application and it was working well, suddenly when I try to get into it by chrome I get this message:

Error 503 service unavailable

When I get into server and following the request there I see this:

Faulting application name: adp-agent.exe, version: 0.0.1.2620, time stamp: 0x664dd85f
< Faulting module name: adp-agent.exe, version: 0.0.1.2620, time stamp: 0x664dd85f
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000018bd82
Faulting process id: 0x5788
Faulting application start time: 0x01daccc7d04515a9
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Acronis\Agent\bin\adp-agent.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Acronis\Agent\bin\adp-agent.exe

Note: the code is working
I have to make it work as soon as possible, and I could not figure out the problem!

Does this issue only happen with chome? how about other browser such as firefox?

the same thing yes

Can't you reproduce this in debug mode? Do you confirm it is not a code issue? Do you use IIS to host the website?

yes I use IIS to host the website, and when I work in code there is no problem

You could also host with Kestrel without IIS, right? If Kestrel works well. Then it will be configuration problem with iis.

Troubleshooting may involve analyzing dumps. Sorry I am not able to do that. If it is IIS issue, this may help https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/http-response-503-service-unavailable-from-iis-one-common/ba-p/1720007

I did create a new application pool and it works, now I want to know what the possible reasons are for that issue.?
